# Deploying App_Data folder to IIS in Orchard CMS

Tags: iis, deployment, orchardcms

I use `Orchard CMS 1.10.1`, I have problem with deploying an existing `App_Data` folder (It already Contains a finished website), I get this error when I try to load website

```
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 
Requested URL: /
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34209
```

When I use a fresh App_Data, It works fine and shows me the Setup Page. But When Click on Finish Setup button, this error comes up :

```
Setup failed: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

________________UPDATE___________________

I deployed this to another server (in different host company) and it worked fine.

**I don't know What this server lack for running Orchard.**
I called them but they had no idea what to do.

I looked at App_Data/logs and this was there:

```
2016-08-24 23:12:25,672 [10] Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost - (null) - A tenant could not be started: Default Attempt number: 0 [(null)]
NHibernate.HibernateException: Could not create the driver from Orchard.Data.Providers.SqlCeDataServicesProvider+OrchardSqlServerCeDriver, Orchard.Framework, Version=1.10.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: Unable to load the native components of SQL Server Compact corresponding to the ADO.NET provider of version 8876. Install the correct version of SQL Server Compact. Refer to KB article 974247 for more details.
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.NativeMethods.LoadNativeBinaries()
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand..ctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at NHibernate.Bytecode.ActivatorObjectsFactory.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at NHibernate.Driver.ReflectionDriveConnectionCommandProvider.CreateCommand()
   at NHibernate.Driver.ReflectionBasedDriver.CreateCommand()
   at NHibernate.Driver.SqlServerCeDriver.Configure(IDictionary`2 settings)
   at Orchard.Data.Providers.SqlCeDataServicesProvider.OrchardSqlServerCeDriver.Configure(IDictionary`2 settings)
   at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2 settings)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2 settings)
   at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.Configure(IDictionary`2 settings)
   at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.NewConnectionProvider(IDictionary`2 settings)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory.BuildSettings(IDictionary`2 properties)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSettings()
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()
   at Orchard.Data.SessionFactoryHolder.BuildSessionFactory()
   at Orchard.Data.SessionFactoryHolder.GetSessionFactory()
   at Orchard.Data.TransactionManager.EnsureSession(IsolationLevel level)
   at Orchard.Data.TransactionManager.GetSession()
   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.get_Session()
   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.get_Table()
   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.Fetch(Expression`1 predicate)
   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.Get(Expression`1 predicate)
   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.Orchard.Data.IRepository<T>.Get(Expression`1 predicate)
   at Orchard.Core.Settings.Descriptor.ShellDescriptorManager.GetDescriptorRecord()
   at Orchard.Core.Settings.Descriptor.ShellDescriptorManager.GetShellDescriptor()
   at Orchard.Environment.ShellBuilders.ShellContextFactory.CreateShellContext(ShellSettings settings)
   at Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost.CreateShellContext(ShellSettings settings)
   at Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost.<CreateAndActivateShells>b__41_1(ShellSettings settings)
2016-08-24 23:12:27,453 [10] Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost - (null) - A tenant could not be started: Default after 1 retries. [(null)]
2016-08-24 23:12:27,938 [10] Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost - (null) - A tenant could not be started: Default Attempt number: 0 [(null)]
NHibernate.HibernateException: Could not create the driver from Orchard.Data.Providers.SqlCeDataServicesProvider+OrchardSqlServerCeDriver, Orchard.Framework, Version=1.10.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: Unable to load the native components of SQL Server Compact corresponding to the ADO.NET provider of version 8876. Install the correct version of SQL Server Compact. Refer to KB article 974247 for more details.
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.NativeMethods.LoadNativeBinaries()
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand..ctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at NHibernate.Bytecode.ActivatorObjectsFactory.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at NHibernate.Driver.ReflectionDriveConnectionCommandProvider.CreateCommand()
   at NHibernate.Driver.ReflectionBasedDriver.CreateCommand()
   at NHibernate.Driver.SqlServerCeDriver.Configure(IDictionary`2 settings)
   at Orchard.Data.Providers.SqlCeDataServicesProvider.OrchardSqlServerCeDriver.Configure(IDictionary`2 settings)
   at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2 settings)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2 settings)
   at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.Configure(IDictionary`2 settings)
   at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.NewConnectionProvider(IDictionary`2 settings)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory.BuildSettings(IDictionary`2 properties)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSettings()
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()
   at Orchard.Data.SessionFactoryHolder.BuildSessionFactory()
   at Orchard.Data.SessionFactoryHolder.GetSessionFactory()
   at Orchard.Data.TransactionManager.EnsureSession(IsolationLevel level)
   at Orchard.Data.TransactionManager.GetSession()
   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.get_Session()
   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.get_Table()
   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.Fetch(Expression`1 predicate)
   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.Get(Expression`1 predicate)
   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.Orchard.Data.IRepository<T>.Get(Expression`1 predicate)
   at Orchard.Core.Settings.Descriptor.ShellDescriptorManager.GetDescriptorRecord()
   at Orchard.Core.Settings.Descriptor.ShellDescriptorManager.GetShellDescriptor()
   at Orchard.Environment.ShellBuilders.ShellContextFactory.CreateShellContext(ShellSettings settings)
   at Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost.CreateShellContext(ShellSettings settings)
   at Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost.<CreateAndActivateShells>b__41_1(ShellSettings settings)
2016-08-24 23:12:29,266 [10] Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost - (null) - A tenant could not be started: Default after 1 retries. [(null)]
2016-08-24 23:12:29,891 [10] Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost - (null) - A tenant could not be started: Default Attempt number: 0 [http://studiosefid.com/]
NHibernate.HibernateException: Could not create the driver from Orchard.Data.Providers.SqlCeDataServicesProvider+OrchardSqlServerCeDriver, Orchard.Framework, Version=1.10.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: Unable to load the native components of SQL Server Compact corresponding to the ADO.NET provider of version 8876. Install the correct version of SQL Server Compact. Refer to KB article 974247 for more details.
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.NativeMethods.LoadNativeBinaries()
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand..ctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at NHibernate.Bytecode.ActivatorObjectsFactory.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at NHibernate.Driver.ReflectionDriveConnectionCommandProvider.CreateCommand()
   at NHibernate.Driver.ReflectionBasedDriver.CreateCommand()
   at NHibernate.Driver.SqlServerCeDriver.Configure(IDictionary`2 settings)
   at Orchard.Data.Providers.SqlCeDataServicesProvider.OrchardSqlServerCeDriver.Configure(IDictionary`2 settings)
   at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2 settings)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2 settings)
   at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.Configure(IDictionary`2 settings)
   at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.NewConnectionProvider(IDictionary`2 settings)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory.BuildSettings(IDictionary`2 properties)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSettings()
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()
   at Orchard.Data.SessionFactoryHolder.BuildSessionFactory()
   at Orchard.Data.SessionFactoryHolder.GetSessionFactory()
   at Orchard.Data.TransactionManager.EnsureSession(IsolationLevel level)
   at Orchard.Data.TransactionManager.GetSession()
   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.get_Session()
   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.get_Table()
   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.Fetch(Expression`1 predicate)
   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.Get(Expression`1 predicate)
   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.Orchard.Data.IRepository<T>.Get(Expression`1 predicate)
   at Orchard.Core.Settings.Descriptor.ShellDescriptorManager.GetDescriptorRecord()
   at Orchard.Core.Settings.Descriptor.ShellDescriptorManager.GetShellDescriptor()
   at Orchard.Environment.ShellBuilders.ShellContextFactory.CreateShellContext(ShellSettings settings)
   at Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost.CreateShellContext(ShellSettings settings)
   at Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost.<CreateAndActivateShells>b__41_1(ShellSettings settings)
2016-08-24 23:12:31,344 [10] Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost - (null) - A tenant could not be started: Default after 1 retries. [http://studiosefid.com/]
2016-08-24 23:12:31,891 [19] Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost - (null) - A tenant could not be started: Default Attempt number: 0 [http://studiosefid.com/]
NHibernate.HibernateException: Could not create the driver from Orchard.Data.Providers.SqlCeDataServicesProvider+OrchardSqlServerCeDriver, Orchard.Framework, Version=1.10.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: Unable to load the native components of SQL Server Compact corresponding to the ADO.NET provider of version 8876. Install the correct version of SQL Server Compact. Refer to KB article 974247 for more details.
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.NativeMethods.LoadNativeBinaries()
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand..ctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at NHibernate.Bytecode.ActivatorObjectsFactory.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at NHibernate.Driver.ReflectionDriveConnectionCommandProvider.CreateCommand()
   at NHibernate.Driver.ReflectionBasedDriver.CreateCommand()
   at NHibernate.Driver.SqlServerCeDriver.Configure(IDictionary`2 settings)
   at Orchard.Data.Providers.SqlCeDataServicesProvider.OrchardSqlServerCeDriver.Configure(IDictionary`2 settings)
   at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2 settings)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2 settings)
   at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.Configure(IDictionary`2 settings)
   at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.NewConnectionProvider(IDictionary`2 settings)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory.BuildSettings(IDictionary`2 properties)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSettings()
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()
   at Orchard.Data.SessionFactoryHolder.BuildSessionFactory()
   at Orchard.Data.SessionFactoryHolder.GetSessionFactory()
   at Orchard.Data.TransactionManager.EnsureSession(IsolationLevel level)
   at Orchard.Data.TransactionManager.GetSession()
   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.get_Session()
   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.get_Table()
   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.Fetch(Expression`1 predicate)
   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.Get(Expression`1 predicate)
   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.Orchard.Data.IRepository<T>.Get(Expression`1 predicate)
   at Orchard.Core.Settings.Descriptor.ShellDescriptorManager.GetDescriptorRecord()
   at Orchard.Core.Settings.Descriptor.ShellDescriptorManager.GetShellDescriptor()
   at Orchard.Environment.ShellBuilders.ShellContextFactory.CreateShellContext(ShellSettings settings)
   at Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHo
```

Comment: It should work with the existing 'App_Data' folder, without the need to setup your site again, but did you added write permission to 'App_Data' folder? did you checked the connection string in 'App_Data/Sites/Default/Settings.txt'?

Comment: Thanks for comment, Yes permission is granted and I use sql ce it doesn't have connection string. I donno what else to check

Comment: Look for a complete error message in `app_data\logs`.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it and will update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log contains the following error message:

```
Unable to load the native components of SQL Server Compact corresponding to the ADO.NET provider of version 8876. Install the correct version of SQL Server Compact. Refer to KB article 974247 for more details.
```

Make sure that you have installed the correct version of SQL Server Compact (the same one as referenced by Orchard).

Comment: Thanks, Big help. I ended up migrating sql ce to sql server and use sql server instead.